# can we conclude that $f$ is a constant?

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose $f(x) \in C[a,b]$ and $\varphi(x)$ is Riemann integrable and satisfy : $\int_a^b\varphi(x)\mathscr{dx}=0$.   $\int_a^bf(x)\varphi(x)\mathscr{dx}=0$       can we conclude that $f(x)\equiv c$?

---

My approach:

for $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then there exists $M$ and $m$ in $\Bbb{R}$,satisfy: $m \leq f(x) \leq M$,so we have $M-f(x)\geq0$,so I can use the mean value theorem:
$$\int_a^b(M-f(x))\varphi(x)\mathscr{dx}=\mu\int_a^b(M-f(x))\mathscr{dx}=0 \Rightarrow \int_a^b f(x)\mathscr{dx} =M(b-a)$$
where $\inf\varphi(x)\leq\mu \leq \sup \varphi(x)$
use MVT to : $$\int_a^b(f(x)-m)\varphi(x)\mathscr{dx}$$we get $\int_a^bf(x)\mathscr{dx}=m(b-a)$ this implies $m=M$,then $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$

Am I right?

---

Comment: What you've actually shown is that $\mu \int_a^b f(x) dx = \mu M(b-a)$.  You cannot conclude that $\mu \neq 0$, and so your argument does not follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example, you could have $\varphi=0$, in which case you will have
$$\int_a^b f(x)\varphi(x)\,dx=0$$
for any $f\in C[a,b]$ whatsoever.

In fact, any function $\varphi$ which is $0$ on some open interval in $[a,b]$ will admit non-constant functions $f\in C[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b f(x)\varphi(x)\,dx=0$.

A slightly less trivial example: for any $t>0$, we could choose $\varphi(x)=x$ on $[-t,t]$, which satisfies $\int_{-t}^t\varphi(x)\,dx=0$, and any even function $f\in C[-t,t]$ will have
$$\begin{align}\int_{-t}^t f(x)\varphi(x)\,dx&=\int_{-t}^0xf(x)\,dx+\int_0^t xf(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^{-t}xf(x)\,dx+\int_0^txf(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\int_0^{t}xf(x)\,dx+\int_0^txf(x)\,dx\\\\
&=0.\end{align}$$

Comment: As an addendum, you will sometimes see people using the fact that the equality holds for *all* test functions $\phi$ to conclude that $f$ is constant.